# Sort Descriptor for string match?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfetchrequest

I'm using a NSFetchRequest for searching for users. In addition to sorting the results by name alphabetically on first name or last name partial matches (which I am already doing), I would like to bring **exact** matches to the beginning of the list.

For example, search string = **"Abra Kadabra"** currently shows

1. "Abra Abra"
2. "Abra Blab"
3. "Abra Kadabra"
4. "Blob Kadabra"
5. "Cookie Kadabra"

But I would instead like it to show

1. "Abra Kadabra"
2. "Abra Abra"
3. "Abra Blab"
4. "Blob Kadabra"
5. "Cookie Kadabra"

I already tried using a block sort descriptor, but because I am using Sqlite for Core Data, that is not possible.

Comment: I dont know how it can be done this way but I would love to know :) up voted/favd

Comment: I can only think of searching for the exact match first and then combined with records from partial fetch. Similar to the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782024/customized-sort-in-nsfetchedresultscontroller