# How to ignore prefixes "A" and "The" when sorting using NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: iphone, database, ios4, sorting, core-data

I am using CoreData to hold books information saved in SQLite database. When sorting by title, I would like to ignore the "A" and "The" prefixes. For example, when having the books: "The Code Book" and "Fermat's Enigma", I wish "Fermat's Enigma" to come before "The Code Book" as "The" should be ignored.

I couldn't find any way to do that besides adding a persistent property that will hold the title without prefixes. (In the example above, that property say 'titleNoPrefixes' should hold "Code Book" string). Sorting based on calculated properties (aka, transient properties) seems to be impossible in CoreData.

Adding a persistent property is obviously a bad database design but I can't see another way. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joshua,

Your problem has almost nothing to do with Core Data as a persistent store, this is a general database sorting on text problem. The traditional solution to your problem is to have a normal form field that is used as the sort category. You might want to lower case everything and strip your noise words for this field. As these are just titles, this isn't particularly expensive, storage wise. Furthermore, this is an insert time operation rather than a search time op. Finally, transient variables only exist in RAM. They are NULL values, I believe, in the datastore. Hence, searching on them is pointless and throws an exception.

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own NSString category that implements:

1. Creating a copy of an NSString with articles removed (assuming you want to keep the original string)
2. Comparing strings returned from #1.

Comment: I guess you mean that the NSString category should implement a compare operation, something like(NSComparisonResult)ignorePrefixesCompare:(NSString *)string. Right? If this is what you mean, I tried this and it is ignored by CoreData. The reason is described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789782/nsfetchedresultscontroller-custom-sort-not-getting-called

Comment: @Joshua it would seem that a persistent property is the way to go, as there is no way to sort on transient data on an SQLite store.

Comment: Okay, I guess these is no other way. Thanks for your replies!